# Internet speed too slow in ubuntu

Tags: wireless, internet, 22.04, router

I am currently using ubuntu 22.04 (Issue was there on previous version also). The wifi speed is normal after turning on wifi, then after 2 or 3 minutes it is becoming too slow. But wifi is working perfectly in my android phone. If i restart the router it will again become normal for 2 to 3 minutes.Please help mee regarding this.

This is output for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth [8086:3166] (rev 99)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 [8086:4210]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

The output for `iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Kerala Vision Broadband"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 14:A7:2B:5F:4D:7E   
          Bit Rate=43.3 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2  Invalid misc:1006   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command in order to identify your WiFi device and maybe find out if there are reported issues, whether i works better with a different driver or needs tweaks, etc. Then check your router settings re: wireless encryption - WPA2-AES as a minimum, no WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and TKIP NEVER!! - and yes, do check then even with other devices working correctly. With proper settings the other devices will work the same or better.

Comment: I am an absolute beginner , can you please tell how to check router settings?

Comment: 1. The Intel WiFi is very well supported and shouldn't have any issues, not even the issues inherent of not using the optimal settings I commented before. 2. `iwconfig` results corroborate your report. Yes, there's a problem and it can be hardware, the card itself or antennae but assuring the optimal settings in the router/AP should be done anyway which leads us to number 3. How to manage the router settings depend on the router. Please check your user's manual. Typically you'd open the router's IP address in a web browser and login with username and password (...)

Comment: Do you know the make and model of your router?

Comment: (...) that you should find in a sticker or in the manual (if you changed it then you should know, of course). Then navigate to the wireless settings page/tab.

Answer (score 0):

That wireless chip should be supported. It seems to be an old model however. Older wireless chips may have trouble picking up wifi properly.

I would suggest making changes to the Router settings. The chip says it's dual band so it should be able to support both 2.4GHz and 5GHz. You can check if your Router is dual band, newer routers should be able to support both.

If your router is dual band, then setting it to 5GHz would be ideal if you aren't that far away from the router. 5GHz does not have that good of a range so if you use your laptop farther away you'll need to connect it to the 2.4 GHz network instead. You may also have to change the wireless channel for 2.4 GHz, channels 1, 6, 11 are recommended. Getting to the settings would vary depending on the make and model. You can contact your ISP for assistance in setting these networks up. Also make sure channel hopping is disabled, that can affect wireless connectivity on older devices too.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
After i called my internet service provider, they logged into some ip address by typing in url, and They configured some settings.After that it started working fine.